# Detecting conflicting classes in classpath with Gradle

Tags: gradle

I accidentally found that my project includes `com.sun.xml.txw2.output.IndentingXMLStreamWriter` twice:

- via `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1`
- via `org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.3.2`

`com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core` is declared as original dependency and `org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2` comes as a transitive dependency for `com.sun.xml.ws:rt`. As a solution I should remove `com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core`.

That brings the question: **how can I detect that same classes are in different JARs on classpath with Gradle**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I found dedicated projects for detecting the discussed problem:

- https://github.com/portingle/classpathHell
- https://github.com/criteo/findjars
- https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin/wiki/Duplicate-Classes-Rule
- https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/net.idlestate.gradle-duplicate-classes-check

I had success with `classpathHell`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.portingle:classpath-hell:1.5"
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java-library'

    apply plugin: 'com.portingle.classpathHell'
    classpathHell {
        configurationsToScan = [ configurations.runtimeClasspath ]
    }
}
```

run as:

```
$ gradle help --task checkClasspath
...
Type
     ClasspathHellTask (classpathHell.ClasspathHellTask)
...

$ gradle checkClasspath
...
configuration 'runtimeClasspath' contains duplicate resource: com/sun/xml/txw2/output/IndentingXMLStreamWriter.class
 found within dependency: org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.3.2
  imported via: org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:2.3.2 <- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.2 <- com.sun.xml.ws:rt:2.3.2
 found within dependency: com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1
  imported via: com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1
...
```

Comment: Hi @gavenkoa - glad you are finding it useful !

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. Notice your first code snippet is missing a closing curly brace.